# Highlight Searched Text in Table bug

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I'm working on a feature that require a user to type in a search item that will search a table for the term and highlight every occurrence. I found some code and got it to work, but I have a bug that I'm not sure how to resolve. In the search input if I hit back space to erase the search term, the unhighlight works until the last character letter. For example, I type in Demo and use back space to delete Demo, only the D is still highlighted.

Below are my code snippets.
NOTE: I have a search and render function that call the highlightActivity and renderReports functions

My CSS

```
.highlight {
    background-color :gold
}

.highlight {
    padding:1px 4px;
    margin: 0 -4px;
}
```

My HTML

```
 <input type="text" id="uniStringSearch" onkeyup="SearchAndRender()"></input>

 <table id="currentReports" class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input name="select_all" id="selectedReports" value="1" type="checkbox" onclick="checkAll(this)" /> </th>
                <th>DATE</th>
                <th>SUMMARY TITLE</th>
                <th>NAME</th>
                <th>ACTIVITY TYPE</th>
                <th>SUB ACTIVITY TYPE</th>
                <th>ACTIVITY DETAILS</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="reports"></tbody>
    </table>
```

HighlightActivity Function

```
function highlightActivity() {

    var searchTerm = $('#uniStringSearch').val();
    var tableID = ''

    switch (webPage) {

        case 'reports':
            tableID = '#currentReports';
            break;
        case 'analysis':
             tableID = '#currentAnalysis';
            break;
        case 'statuses':
            tableID = '#currentStatuses';
            break;
        default:
    }

    $(tableID).find('.highlight').removeClass('highlight');

    $(tableID).find('tr td').each(function () {
        if ((this).attr('data-search') !== 'false') {
            var text = $(this).text();
            var textLowerCase = text.toLowerCase();
            var pos = textLowerCase.indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
            var regex = new RegExp(searchTerm, 'ig');

            text = text.replace(regex, (match, $1) => {
                return '<span class="highlight">' + match + '</span>';
            });
            $(this).html(text);
            if (pos !== -1) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    if ($(this).parent().find('.highlight').is(':empty')) {
                        $('.highlight').remove();
                    }
                }.bind(this), 0);
            }
            else {
                $(this).text(text);
            }

        }
        if ($(this).parent().find('.highlight').length > 0) {
            $(this).parent().show();
        }
        else {
            $(this).parent().hide();
        }

    });
}
```

Render Reports Function

```
function renderReports(items) {
    
    var html = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
    {
        html = '<tr><td><input type="checkbox" id="selectedReports" onchange="chkInputChanged(event)"/></td>'
        html += '<td>' + items[i].DateActivity + '</td>'
        html += '<td>' + items[i].Name + '</td>'
        html += '<td>' + items[i].ActivityType + '</td>'
        html += '<td>' + items[i].SubActivityType + '</td>'
        html += '<td id="searchActivityDetails">' + items[i].ActivityDetails + '</td></tr>'
    }
    
    $('#reports').empty();
    $('#reports').append(html);

}
```

ALSO....one more thing, is there a way to have my highlight function to target a specific column? For example Summary Title and Activity Details

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question.

Comment: Better to make a runnable snippet as the minimal example. Use the `<>` icon on the text editor toolbar to create a fiddle-like interface.